# How can construct a new array based on multiple property values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 3 people in the house ['John', 'Jane', 'Jack'],

We kept track of who opened/closed the door.

```
logs = [
  { name: "John", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "closed" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "closed" },
];
```

As you can see only 2 people `['Jane', 'Jack']` that opened and closed the door properly.

programmatically, I did these 3 steps to come to know that John is the person who opened and never closed the door.

```
let openers = logs.reduce((acc, log) => {
  if (log.status === "opened") {
    acc.push(log.name);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(openers);

let closers = logs.reduce((acc, log) => {
  if (log.status === "closed") {
    acc.push(log.name);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(closers);

let result = [];
closers.forEach((closer) => {
  if (openers.includes(closer)) {
    result.push(closer);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

I was trying to do these in one go in a single `reduce()`, but I'm not too sure.

Can someone help me improve what I got

```js
logs = [
  { name: "John", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "closed" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "closed" },
];

let openers = logs.reduce((acc, log) => {
  if (log.status === "opened") {
    acc.push(log.name);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(openers);

let closers = logs.reduce((acc, log) => {
  if (log.status === "closed") {
    acc.push(log.name);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(closers);

let result = [];
closers.forEach((closer) => {
  if (openers.includes(closer)) {
    result.push(closer);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

?

Comment: From the question it sounds like there is only one door, and it seems that the log entries are supposed to be in sequence. However that would mean that a door that is opened can be opened again, which doesn't make sense. Does every person have their own door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a single `.reduce()` that keeps track of door status by name:

```js
logs = [
  { name: "John", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "closed" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "closed" },
];

let statuses = logs.reduce((acc, log) => {
  acc[log.name] = (log.status === 'opened');
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(statuses);
let culprits = Object.keys(statuses).filter(name => statuses[name]);
console.log(culprits);
```

Output:

```
{
  "John": true,
  "Jane": false,
  "Jack": false
}
[
  "John"
]
```

Comment: I like your solution a lot. How comes your codes never look for when someone `closed` ? Did I overlook something ? Can you please give me inputs on that a bit more ?

Comment: The door only has two states, that's why it is sufficient to check only for `(log.status === 'opened')`

Answer (score 1):

It's bound to be a little more involved, because people can open and close the door multiple times.

This approach finds the people for which the number of openings/closings don't match. It [reduces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the input to an intermediate object where for every name, it adds 1 to the value if the door was opened, and subtracts one if the door was closed. After that, it's just a matter of getting the object's [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the names for which the count is 0.

```js
const logs = [
  { name: "John", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "closed" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "closed" },
];

const result = Object.entries(logs.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v.name] = a[v.name] || 0;
  a[v.name] += v.status === 'opened' ? 1 : -1;
  return a;
}, {})).filter(([_, v]) => v).map(([k]) => k);

console.log(result);
```

There are additional complexities if you would take the order of openings and closings into account, but the question does not provide enough details to address those.

Comment: I think keeping track of count open/close is overkill because you can't open a door twice, then close twice, e.g. are always open & close sequences

Comment: @PeterThoeny Then again, from the input it looks like the door is opened three times in sequence, and then closed twice. Unless every person has their own door? Not enough details provided in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
const result = logs.reduce((accVal, x) => {
    if (logs.find(y => x.name == y.name && x.status == "opened" && y.status == "closed" )) {
        return Object.assign(accVal, accVal.opened_and_closed.splice(logs.length, 0, x.name));
    }
    else if (logs.find(y => x.name == y.name && x.status == "opened" && y.status != "closed" )) {
        return Object.assign(accVal, accVal.opened_not_closed.splice(logs.length, 0, x.name));
    }
    else {
        return accVal;
    }
},
{ "opened_and_closed": [ ], "opened_not_closed": [ ] } 
);
```

The `result` value:

```
{
  opened_and_closed: [ 'Jane', 'Jack' ],
  opened_not_closed: [ 'John' ]
}
```

Comment: that has an exponential time complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for the comment. Please explain. Also, The question post has no such requirement.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen _"I was trying to do these in one go in a single reduce(), but I'm not too sure."_ - That was the requirement of the question post.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen _"I have 3 people in the house ['John', 'Jane', 'Jack'],"_ (from the question post). How does the "time compexity" apply to this data?

Comment: In this case, time complexity is expressed in terms of the number of items in the log array, not the number of people in the house. For the current example input (i.e. 5 entries), the difference is negligible. For a couple of thousands of entries, your solution is going to slow down significantly. For a couple of million entries, the galaxy will implode before your algorithm finishes computation. Time complexity *always* needs to be factored in.

Comment: I am _specifically_ asking about this _"I have 3 people in the house ['John', 'Jane', 'Jack'],"_ and this: _"I was trying to do these in one go in a single reduce(), but I'm not too sure."_. These were the requirements (as in Software Requirements) for this question post.

Comment: For further reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements

Comment: you could have taken my original comment at face value, run some benchmarks, and notice that even with only 1,000 entries in the `logs` array, your solution runs at least 100 times slower than other solutions that have been presented. At 2,000 entries, that goes up to 500 times slower. At 3,000 entries, it's 900 times slower. That's exponential time complexity at work for you. Engineering a solution with acceptable runtime performance is what we commonly refer to as a [non-functional requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement).

Comment: The number of inputs in the question is necessarily small. Adding more entries would do nothing to clarify the problem, and would run into Stack Overflow's restrictions on question size. Arguably, for the given number of inputs, one wouldn't even need an algorithm to come up with a solution, as it can be seen on sight. When designing an algorithm, however, [computational complexity](https://w.wiki/67HY) is probably the most important factor (after correctness) to take into account, as it has a direct impact on system scalability. That's why it's prominently taught in computer science courses.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Does your own answer conform with the software requirements specified in the question post? _"I have 3 people in the house ['John', 'Jane', 'Jack']," and this: "I was trying to do these in one go in a single reduce(), but I'm not too sure."_. I will explain it again: small amount of data, simple calculation and using one `Arrays#reduce` method.

Comment: Do you count more than one call to `reduce()` in my answer?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The answer doesnt solve the whole problem in a single reduce.

Comment: The answer that was accepted by the original poster, also uses additional calls to `Object.keys()` and `filter()` to come to a final solution. It only materially differs from mine in the sense it uses a boolean instead of a number to keep track of the state of door openings/closings. Assuming that the original poster has the best understanding of their requirements feels like a safe assumption to make. As is the assumption that they prefer an efficient solution over an inefficient one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as other answerers have, that there should always be a open/close sequence for a given person, here's a solution that uses a single [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) statement with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of who opened but hasn't closed the door:

```js
const logs = [
  { name: "John", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "opened" },
  { name: "Jane", status: "closed" },
  { name: "Jack", status: "closed" },
];

const result = logs.reduce((a, { name, status }) => {
  status === 'opened' ? a.add(name) : a.delete(name);
  return a;
}, new Set());

console.log([...result]);
```

This solution has a runtime complexity of `O(n)` and does not result in duplicate entries should one person open and close the door multiple times.